# Problem between Organic Groups and Articles/Pages?

Tags: 7, organic-groups

I am currently working within Drupal 7 and I have all of the Views and Organic Groups modules enabled. Currently when I create a new article or page on my site it appears fine on the front page of the website. Yet when I click to view/edit the article/page I am unable to see the body of the article/page even though I can see it on the front page.

When I disable the module Organic Groups Field Access I am able to see the body of the article/page at the front page, view and edit screens.

Is there some way to keep the module Organic Groups Field Access and still be able to see the body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem too. It turns out the current 'stable' version of Organic Groups is not so stable. This along with some other annoying bugs are fixed in the development version of OG. Give that a try :-)